# How to place images dynamically using Aspose.PDF in C#?

Tags: c#, image, pdf, aspose

I have a C# script where I am using the Aspose.PDF library. 
I am trying to place multiple images with a bit of a spacing vertically.

Here is what I am doing.

```
  // Create pdf document
        Aspose.Pdf.Document document = new Aspose.Pdf.Document();
        Aspose.Pdf.Page page = document.Pages.Add();


        Aspose.Pdf.Text.TextFragment text = new Aspose.Pdf.Text.TextFragment("Einstein Picture");
        page.Paragraphs.Add(text);

        Aspose.Pdf.Rectangle rectangle = new Aspose.Pdf.Rectangle(100, 600, 300, 800);
        Aspose.Pdf.Rectangle rectangle1 = new Aspose.Pdf.Rectangle(100, 400, 300, 800);

        page.AddImage("C:/Users/Alan/Desktop/image.gif", rectangle);
        page.AddImage("C:/Users/Alan/Desktop/s.jpeg", rectangle1);


        document.Save("C:/Users/Alan/Desktop/Testpdf.pdf", Aspose.Pdf.SaveFormat.Pdf);
```

How can I perfectly align pictures vertically with a bit of gap no matter how many pictures there are?

Currently the picture looks like this. [image: PDF image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I request you to use below code snippet on your end and then share your kind feedback with us. This will enable you to place multiple images with a bit vertical spacing.

```
        // Instantiate Document object
        var pdf = new Aspose.Pdf.Document();
        //Add a page to the document
        var pdfImageSection = pdf.Pages.Add();
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Aspose Files\images\");
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.jpg");
        //Iterate through multiple images
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open);
            System.Drawing.Image img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(stream);
            var image = new Aspose.Pdf.Image { ImageStream = stream };
            //Set appearance properties
            image.FixHeight = 300;
            image.FixWidth = 300;
            //Set margins for proper spacing and alignment
            image.Margin = new MarginInfo(5, 5, 5, 5);
            //Add the image to paragraphs of the document
            pdfImageSection.Paragraphs.Add(image);
        }
        //Save resultant document
        pdf.Save(@"D:\Aspose Files\Image2Pdf_out.pdf");
```

You were simply adding an image on a PDF page whereas this code snippet adds an image to Paragraphs collection and setting the margin property of image object fixes the alignment and spacing of the images.

Please let us know if you need any further assistance. We will be glad to help. For Aspose documentation to manipulate images is [here](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Manipulate+Images).

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Please no link-only answers on stack overflow.

Comment: Great! By the way, feel free to keep the original link in the answer, e.g. saying "for further details go here" or "for an in-depth coverage read this".